# Get Table's header id or index when clicking on it

Tags: qooxdoo

Qooxdoo experts :

```
oTable.getPaneScroller(0).getHeader().addListener('click', function(e) { ..... }, this);
```

I can call some function, but what I really need is to get the column's label or index in which I'm clicking to use it as a parameter. I can't find the proper syntax for the child's label, still a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's exactly what you need but you may want to try this:

```
oTable.getPaneScroller(0).getHeader().addListener('click', function(e) { 
    var pageX = e.getDocumentLeft();
    var col = oTable.getPaneScroller(0)._getColumnForPageX(pageX);
    var label = oTable.getPaneScroller(0).getHeader().getHeaderWidgetAtColumn(col).getLabel();
    alert(label);
  });
```

This is certainly not the "cleanest" solution one could think of, but who cares if it serves your purpose ;-)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed !!! Thanks a lot for your code my friend it works perfect for me. Saludos